# Getting a gmail contact Photo using Curl

Tags: php, curl, photo, google-contacts-api

I have created a class managing the connection to Google Contacts API, authenticate and return the contacts.

I've successfully got the contacts list, But I didn't yet manage to get the contact photo. This is my html code :

```
<img src="<?= $service->getPhoto($contact['image']) ?>" />
```

and this is my php:

```
public function getPhoto($url = false){

        if(!$url)
            return false;

        $url = urlencode($url.'&access_token='.$this->_access_token);
        //echo $url.'&access_token='.$this->_access_token;
        $curl = curl_init($url);

       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);

        $image = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        return $image;

    }
```

Note that the $url argument is the url provided by the contacts data returned by the Google API, it's like as the following:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/{userEmail}/{contactID}
```

This is an exemple of an URL (according to my project) :

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/example%40gmail.com/ABCDEFGHIJK2345
```

Sometimes the contactId contains a '/'

The error message from Google is :

```
401. That's an error.

There was an error in your request. That's all we know.
```

Did I miss something?

**NOTE:** I tried with urlencode, urldecode  and tried without using them...But I got the same problem. Also, the contacts I'm testing with have gmail photos.

Answer (score 1):

You are encoding your whole url and probably which is causing the mess!?

```
$url = $url . '&access_token=' . urlencode($this->_access_token);
```

Comment: Thank you +1, but even if I urlencode the token only, I get the same error.

Also .. I noted that the gd:etag is not returned for any image in the response. Even if the contacts have photos.

Comment: Run the code with `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` and update your question with the log msg.

Comment: Thank you Sabuj Hassa, I've just solved the problem, I will post the solution in a separated answer, Oof !! I've been struggling since this morning :)

Answer (score 0):

I've finally solved the problem, and this is what I did:

I changed the '&' to '?' in the $url

```
$url.'&access_token='.$this->_access_token
```

changed to :

```
$url.'?access_token='.$this->_access_token
```

Since access_token is the first parameter ... and I removed the curl, I just returned the $url as it is and put it in the image src.

Although it's somehow solved, I don't know if it's okey to put the access_token in the src of the image (which can be viewed by any client side user).